# Insert First Set of Data To EF Code-First Using Repository Pattern.

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i am trying to insert first set of data to database using Entity Framework Code-First And generic repository pattern. My POCO classes have these relations:

- Student has Many-to-Many Relation with Lessons
- Student has One-to-Many Relation with Collage

Here are my POCO classes:

```
public class Student : EntityBase
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Lessons = new HashSet<Lesson>(); 
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //FK Collage
    public int CollageId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    public virtual Collage Collages { get; set; }
}

public class Lesson : EntityBase
{
    public Lesson()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>(); 
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Collage : EntityBase
{
    public Collage()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>(); 
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my Mappings:

```
public class StudentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        //ToTable("TblStudent");

        HasRequired<Collage>(x => x.Collages)
            .WithMany(e => e.Students)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.CollageId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasMany<Lesson>(x => x.Lessons)
            .WithMany(e => e.Students)
            .Map(i =>
            {
                i.MapLeftKey("StudentFKId");
                i.MapRightKey("LessonFKId");
                i.ToTable("TblStudent_Lesson");
            });

    }
}
```

Now in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Repository<Student> _reStu = new Repository<Student>();
    _reStu.Add(new Student { Name = "Test", CollageId = 0, Collages = null, Lessons = null });
    _reStu.save();

    return View();
}
```

I get this Error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Students_dbo.TblCollage_CollageId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "test2", table "dbo.TblCollage", column 'Id'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

I know that i have a relation between tables but how can i insert the first set of data when there is a relation? should i include my relation after i pass the data within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i insert the first set of data when there is a relation?

`CollageId` is a non-nullable column, which means that you need to set it. Currently your model says that every `Student` **must** have one `College`, so SQL Server will not allow you to insert an invalid row.

So in order to add any `Student` you need to add a `College` first.

> should i include my relation after i pass the data within?

EF is pretty smart, so you should be able to go with either of these approaches.

Create the `College` while you create the `Student`.

```
Repository<Student> _reStu = new Repository<Student>();
_reStu.Add(new Student { Name = "Test", Collages = new College { Name = "TestCollege" }, Lessons = null });
_reStu.save();
```

Or create the `College` first, and then the `Student`.

```
Repository<College> _reColl = new Repository<College>();
var college = new College
{
    Name = "TestCollege"
};
_reColl.Add(college)
_reColl.save();

// As long as you have the same reference your college will get an Id after you inserted it.

Repository<Student> _reStu = new Repository<Student>();
_reStu.Add(new Student { Name = "Test", CollegeId = college.Id, Lessons = null });
_reStu.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should add an existing CollageId to your Student object or you should create a new Collage (if it's necessary) object and set it as Collage property of the Student object.

The reason of that error is database constraint which doesn't allow to add students without CollageId set, but you try to save a student without Collage (CollageId = 0).