# Adding to context in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need a help regarding Entity Framework. I have a class that has a virtual `supplier` property

```
public class Invoices
{
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SupplierId")]
    public virtual Supplier SupplierDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the structure of the `supplier` class

```
public class Supplier
{
    [Key, Column("SupplierId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAdd { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: how can I add an invoice to my context without adding a supplier exists in my database?

Here's my code for the adding

```
public ActionResult AddInvoice(Invoices inv)
{
    context.invoices.add(inv);
    return View();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated - hoping someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: And what is the issue you get? The only problem I see would be missing `context.SaveChanges()`

Comment: `SupplierId` is non-nullable. So you need to set the `Supplier`. See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826138/insert-first-set-of-data-to-ef-code-first-using-repository-pattern/41826550#41826550)

Comment: but i need also to add the details if it doesnt exist to my supplier directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by this time ive manage to add a small code to reach the specific feat.

please see below code

```
   public ActionResult AddNewAsset(AssetHeaderDetails entity)
    {
        if (IsExist<Supplier>(entity.SupplierDetails))
        {
            entity.SupplierId = entity.SupplierDetails.Id;
            entity.SupplierDetails = null;
        }
        AddDataToContext(entity);
        AddToLookUp("AssetItemDesc", entity.Description,     entity.Description);
        if(entity.AssetItemDetails != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in entity.AssetItemDetails)
            {
                AddToLookUp("AssetItemDetail", item.ItemDescription, item.ItemType);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("AddNewAsset");
    }
```

its looks like fishy but it can manage a bit..thanks to all who comment

any better code? please comment here and i will try to change the code.. BIG THANKS .. :D

Answer (score 1):

Set the SupplierId property to a nullable int type (int?). This will allow for inserting invoices without a linked supplier.

Comment: but i need also to add the details if it doesnt exist to my supplier directory